# Error when registering Service in Manifest: Top level element is not completed

Tags: android, android-intent, maps, manifest

For my App i have implemented geofencing, and now I need to register the service to receive the Intent the geofence sends once the device enters the specified area.

When i add the code

```
<service
android:name="my.devname.appname.IntentReceivingClass"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:exported="false">
</service>
```

I get "Top level element is not completed"

this is my current IntentReceivingClass

```
public class IntentEmpfanger extends IntentService {

public IntentEmpfanger() {
    super("IntentEmpfanger");
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
   makeNotification();
}


protected void makeNotification(){
...
}
```

I suspect there might be another method i have to implement but i haven't found anything and Android Studio doesn't give me a warning either that usually occurs when i have not realized a method i have to implement.

I have used [this tutorial by google](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) as a reference for my project

Any help is very much appreciated
Thank You

Comment: Can you part your entire manifest? And have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tYcKpemQ    here is my complete manifest. I just tried despite the red markings and the app (including service) still runs though.